# How to install "authorizenet/magento-module-authorizenet" on Magento 2.4?

Tags: payment-methods, installation, composer, authorize.net, magento2.4

There is no Authorize.net payments in Magento 2.4 [by default](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-DevBlog/Deprecation-of-Magento-core-payment-integrations/ba-p/426445). Magento recommends to "*use the [official extension](https://marketplace.magento.com/authorizenet-magento-module-authorizenet.html) from marketplace instead*".

'*Official extension*' is compatible with Magento Open Source 2.2 & 2.3 versions only.

I tried to install '*official extension*' to Magento 2.3.5-p2. This extension is metapackage, it just contains links to other modules:

```
{
    "name": "authorizenet/magento-module-authorizenet",
    "description": "Authorize.Net Payment module suite for Magento",
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "type": "metapackage",
    "require": {
        "php": "7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0|~7.2.0|~7.3.0",
        "authorizenet/magento-module-centinel": "1.0.1",
        "authorizenet/magento-module-creditcard": "1.0.1",
        "authorizenet/magento-module-echeck": "1.0.1",
        "authorizenet/magento-module-paypalexpress": "1.0.1",
        "authorizenet/magento-module-visacheckout": "1.0.1",
        "authorizenet/magento-module-webhooks": "1.0.2"
    },
    "license": [
        "proprietary"
    ]
}
```

There are no `authorizenet/magento-module-*` on https://packagist.org/ (in public access). I tried to generate access keys and to use Magento repo (https://repo.magento.com) but I have an error:

```
$ composer require authorizenet/magento-module-authorizenet
Using version ^1.0 for authorizenet/magento-module-authorizenet
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information                                                                                                Updating dependencies (including require-dev)         
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for authorizenet/magento-module-authorizenet ^1.0 -> satisfiable by authorizenet/magento-module-authorizenet[1.0.1].
    - authorizenet/magento-module-authorizenet 1.0.1 requires authorizenet/magento-module-centinel 1.0.1 -> no matching package found.
```

What is the right way to install Authorize.Net payment methods to Magento 2.4?

*** EDIT ***

I've 'bought' this module at marketplace. It's free:

[image: orders history]

Comment: First buy that module from the marketplace then try

Comment: I've bought it, will add screenshot to the question

Comment: we use this ext - https://store.paradoxlabs.com/magento2-authorize-net-cim-payment-module.html

Comment: The module pictured is listed as working only in M2.3 and if it does operate in 2.4 it tops out at php 7.3.

Anyone using the Authorize.net module with M2.4 and php 7.4?

Comment: The underlying Authorize.net SDK is not compatible with 7.4, so in order to use the Magento module, you have to fork/patch the SDK and set as a preference instead of the one declared by the core Authorize.net module.  https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-php/issues/383