# Can't upgrade Magento from 2.3.5-p1 to 2.4.2 due to extension errors

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.4

I am trying to upgrade Magento from 2.3.5-p1 to 2.4.2. I have run `composer require magento/composer-root-update-plugin=~1.0 --no-update` and `composer update`. Then I got error on some extensions. One of them was for owebia/magento2-module-advanced-shipping-setting. So I have followed as described at https://github.com/owebia/magento2-module-advanced-shipping. But now I run `composer require owebia/magento2-module-advanced-shipping:^6.0.1` I am getting below error.

```
Problem 1
    - owebia/magento2-module-shared-php-config 6.0.1 requires php ~7.4.0|~8.0.0|~8.1.0|~8.2.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - owebia/magento2-module-advanced-shipping 6.0.1 requires owebia/magento2-module-shared-php-config ^6.0.1 -> satisfiable by owebia/magento2-module-shared-php-config[6.0.1].
    - Installation request for owebia/magento2-module-advanced-shipping ^6.0.1 -> satisfiable by owebia/magento2-module-advanced-shipping[6.0.1].
```

If I change the PHP version to 7.4 then I am getting another error as shown below.

```
Problem 1
    - amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-with-amazon-core-module 3.4.1 requires php ~7.1.3||~7.2.0||~7.3.0 -> your PHP version (7.4.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-with-amazon-core-module 3.4.1 requires php ~7.1.3||~7.2.0||~7.3.0 -> your PHP version (7.4.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-with-amazon-core-module 3.4.1 requires php ~7.1.3||~7.2.0||~7.3.0 -> your PHP version (7.4.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Installation request for amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-with-amazon-core-module (locked at 3.4.1) -> satisfiable by amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-with-amazon-core-module[3.4.1].
```

How can I upgrade Magento?

Below is the composer.json

```
{
    "name": "magento/project-community-edition",
    "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "version": "2.1.5",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "require": {
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.4.2",
        "composer/composer": "@alpha",
        "mailchimp/mc-magento2": "*",
        "authorizenet/magento-module-authorizenet": "^1.0",
        "doofinder/doofinder-magento2": "^0.4.13",
        "sendinblue/module-sendinblue": "^2.1",
        "pronko/google-adwords": "1.1.2",
        "magento/composer-root-update-plugin": "~1.0",
        "owebia/magento2-module-advanced-shipping": "^6.0.1"
    },
    "config": {
        "use-include-path": true,
        "disable-tls": false
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
            "Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"
        },
        "psr-0": {
            "": "app/code/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "alpha",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        }
    ],
    "extra": {
        "magento-force": "override"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "allure-framework/allure-phpunit": "~1.2.0",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.16.0",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
        "magento/magento-coding-standard": "~3.0.0",
        "magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "2.4.5",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "~2.7.1",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "^2.8.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "~5.0.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "~3.5.4"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps

Step 1. Download ver:2.4.2 `composer.json` by following command in other **temp directory**.

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition:2.4.2 .
```

Step 2. Take backup current `composer.json` and `composer.lock` files

Step 3. Upload the `composer.json` from temp directory to your project directory

Step 4. Run `composer update` command

Step 5. Run setup upgrade and deploy commands

Step 6. Now install other require modules

Comment: It is a backup of the live site I am trying to upgrade, it has data

Comment: Okay, Please try these steps, It's easy method to upgrade Magento version.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this `--ignore-platform-reqs` after every composer command to ignore PHP version error as some of your modules are not compatible with the current PHP version.

```
composer update --ignore-platform-reqs

composer require owebia/magento2-module-advanced-shipping:^6.0.1 --ignore-platform-reqs
```

After the successful upgrade, you have to test these extensions proactively.

One more thing you should use the PHP version which is compatible with the Magento version you are upgrading to, check the below link:

**For 2.4.2: PHP version should be 7.4**

https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/system-requirements.html

**UPDATE:**

Update your `composer.json` with below code and then run `composer update --ignore-platform-reqs`

```
{
    "name": "magento/project-community-edition",
    "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "version": "2.4.2",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "require": {
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.4.2",
        "composer/composer": "@alpha",
        "mailchimp/mc-magento2": "*",
        "authorizenet/magento-module-authorizenet": "^2.0",
        "doofinder/doofinder-magento2": "^0.4.13",
        "sendinblue/module-sendinblue": "^2.1",
        "pronko/google-adwords": "1.1.2",
        "magento/composer-root-update-plugin": "~1.0",
        "owebia/magento2-module-advanced-shipping": "^6.0.1",
        "magento/module-vault": "101.1.*"
    },
    "config": {
        "use-include-path": true,
        "disable-tls": false
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
            "Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"
        },
        "psr-0": {
            "": "app/code/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "alpha",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        }
    ],
    "extra": {
        "magento-force": "override"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "allure-framework/allure-phpunit": "~1.2.0",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.16.0",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
        "magento/magento-coding-standard": "~3.0.0",
        "magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "2.4.5",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "~2.7.1",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "^2.8.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "~5.0.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "~3.5.4"
    }
}
```

Comment: Still getting the error `authorizenet/magento-module-echeck 1.0.1 requires magento/module-vault 101.0.*|101.1.* -> satisfiable by magento/module-vault[101.1.5, 101.1.7-p2, 101.1.7-p1, 101.1.7, 101.1.6-p1, 101.1.6, 101.1.4-p2, 101.1.4, 101.0.8, 101.0.7, 101.1.3, 101.0.6, 101.1.2, 101.1.1, 101.1.0, 101.0.5, 101.0.4, 101.0.3, 101.0.2, 101.0.1, 101.0.0, 101.0.0-rc30, 101.0.0-rc23, 101.0.0-rc22, 101.0.0-rc21].`

Comment: @Akhilesh, paste your composer.json in your question. So that I can look into the issue

Comment: Try by adding "magento/module-vault": "101.1.*" in your composer.json's "require": {"magento/module-vault": "101.1.*", } then run composer update --ignore-platform-reqs

Comment: Added composer.json content

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/367941/update-2-3-4-2-4-x-composer-update-composer-root-update-plugin-it-could-not/367943#367943

Comment: @ArunSharma I update your composer.json. Please check and update me.

Comment: @Akhilesh updated composer.json you can try the updated code in your system

Comment: I tried with that and got a huge list of error `Problem 1
    - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.4.2 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.4.2].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.4.2 requires magento/module-vault 101.2.2 -> satisfiable by magento/module-vault[101.2.2] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.].........`

Comment: Then I changed the `magento/module-vault` version to 101.2.2 and tried. Then I got  the error `Problem 1
    - authorizenet/magento-module-creditcard 1.0.1 requires magento/module-vault 101.0.*|101.1.* -> satisfiable by magento/module-vault[101.1.7-p2, 101.1.7-p1, 101.1.7, 101.1.6-p1, 101.1.6, 101.1.4-p2, 101.1.5, 101.1.4, 101.0.8, 101.0.7, 101.1.3, 101.0.6, 101.1.2, 101.1.1, 101.1.0, 101.0.5, 101.0.4, 101.0.3, 101.0.2, 101.0.1, 101.0.0, 101.0.0-rc30, 101.0.0-rc23, 101.0.0-rc22, 101.0.0-rc21] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability...`

Comment: Your tried `composer update --ignore-platform-reqs` or simple `composer update` ??

Comment: Try by updating the version of authorize.net `"authorizenet/magento-module-authorizenet": "^2.0"` as you can check here which version is compatible with Magento 2.4 https://commercemarketplace.adobe.com/rootways-module-authorizenetcim.html

Answer (score 0):

**Match your composer.json file**

```
{
    "name": "magento/project-community-edition",
    "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "version": "2.4.2",
    "require": {
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.4.2",
        "magento/composer-root-update-plugin": "~1.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "exclude-from-classmap": [
            "**/dev/**",
            "**/update/**",
            "**/Test/**"
        ],
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ],
        "psr-0": {
            "": [
                "app/code/",
                "generated/code/"
            ]
        },
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
            "Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"
        }
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "allure-framework/allure-phpunit": "~1.2.0",
        "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": "^0.7.0",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.16.0",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
        "magento/magento-coding-standard": "*",
        "magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "^3.0",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "~2.7.1",
        "phpcompatibility/php-compatibility": "^9.3",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "^2.8.0",
        "phpstan/phpstan": ">=0.12.3 <=0.12.23",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "~5.0.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "~3.5.4"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "gene/bluefoot": "*"
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\PhpStan\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/PhpStan/",
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        }
    ],
    "extra": {
        "magento-force": "override"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I tried your composer.json in my local and successfully updated it to 2.4.2.

**You must have PHP Version 7.4.X and Composer version 2.2.x**

**composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "magento/project-community-edition",
    "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin": true,
            "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": true,
            "magento/composer-root-update-plugin": true,
            "magento/inventory-composer-installer": true,
            "magento/magento-composer-installer": true
        }
    },
    "version": "2.4.2",
    "require": {
        "composer/composer": "@alpha",
        "doofinder/doofinder-magento2": "^0.12.0",
        "magento/composer-root-update-plugin": "~1.1",
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.4.2",
        "mailchimp/mc-magento2": "*",
        "owebia/magento2-module-advanced-shipping": "^6.0",
        "sendinblue/module-sendinblue": "^2.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "exclude-from-classmap": [
            "**/dev/**",
            "**/update/**",
            "**/Test/**"
        ],
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ],
        "psr-0": {
            "": [
                "app/code/",
                "generated/code/"
            ]
        },
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
            "Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"
        }
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "allure-framework/allure-phpunit": "~1.2.0",
        "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": "^0.7.0",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.16.0",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
        "magento/magento-coding-standard": "*",
        "magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "^3.0",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "~2.7.1",
        "phpcompatibility/php-compatibility": "^9.3",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "^2.8.0",
        "phpstan/phpstan": ">=0.12.3 <=0.12.23",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "~5.0.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "~3.5.4"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "gene/bluefoot": "*"
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\PhpStan\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/PhpStan/",
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "alpha",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "repositories": {
        "local": {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "packages/*/*"
        },
        "magento": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "magento-force": "override"
    }
}
```

Please check the below points.

**sendinblue/module-sendinblue** -> https://github.com/sendinblue/magento2-plugin/tree/master

**authorizenet/magento-module-authorizenet** -> You should Purchase this module from Marketplace and add you key to auth.json and run below command

link : https://commercemarketplace.adobe.com/partner/RootwaysInc

Reference: [How to install "authorizenet/magento-module-authorizenet" on Magento 2.4?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/321933/how-to-install-authorizenet-magento-module-authorizenet-on-magento-2-4)

```
composer require authorizenet/magento-module-authorizenet
```

**pronko/google-adwords** -> https://commercemarketplace.adobe.com/pronko-google-adwords.html

Also read this document where they provide installation steps.

Link : https://commercemarketplace.adobe.com/media/catalog/product/pronko-google-adwords-1-1-2-ce/installation_guides.pdf

**owebia/magento2-module-advanced-shipping** -> https://github.com/owebia/magento2-module-advanced-shipping/tree/master

**owebia/magento2-module-shared-php-config** -> https://github.com/owebia/magento2-module-shared-php-config/tree/master

**Note:** Download these updated files where I updated your composer.json file. [Click Here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1tIiegxcy7tLh1CLQXLTtz5GIMA7GUjxQ?usp=sharing)

I place some packages at the below location to fix composer error.

**RootMagento/packages/owebia/magento2-module-advanced-shipping/** -> https://github.com/owebia/magento2-module-advanced-shipping/tree/master

**RootMagento/packages/owebia/magento2-module-shared-php-config/** -> https://github.com/owebia/magento2-module-shared-php-config/tree/master

**RootMagento/packages/sendinblue/module-sendinblue/** -> https://github.com/sendinblue/magento2-plugin/tree/master

When you install any marketplace module please read this : https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/install-magento-marketplace-module-using-compose/

**Maybe this helps you.**