# update 2.3.4 > 2.4.x, composer update: composer-root-update-plugin, it could not be found in any version

Tags: magento2.3, upgrade, composer, magento-upgrade, composer-update

Hi i am try to update magento from 2.3.4 to 2.4.x.

I am followed those guides:
https://www.codextblog.com/magento-2/upgrade-magento-version-2-3-x-2-4-0/
https://www.mgt-commerce.com/tutorial/how-to-upgrade-magento-2-3-to-2-4/
https://magecomp.com/blog/upgrade-magento-version-from-2-3-to-2-4/

After commands:

```
composer require magento/composer-root-update-plugin=~1.0 --no-update

composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.2 --no-update
```

on `composer update`, i got the errors:

````
[glow_2@hs23 httpdocs]$ composer update
The "magento/inventory-composer-installer" plugin was skipped because it requires a Plugin API version ("^1.1") that does not match your Composer installation ("2.3.0"). You may need to run composer update with the "--no-plugins" option.

Loading composer repositories with package information
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine

Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires magento/composer-root-update-plugin, it could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 2
    - Root composer.json requires magento/product-community-edition 2.4.x, found magento/product-community-edition[2.3.4] but it does not match the constraint.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see  for more details.
 - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it

Read  for further common problems.

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.```
````

What could problem 1 and 2 mean? Has this happened to anyone else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow these steps

Step 1. Download ver:2.4.2 `composer.json` by following command in other **temp directory.**

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition:2.4.2 .
```

Step 2. Take backup current `composer.json` and `composer.lock` files

Step 3. Upload the `composer.json` from **temp** directory to your project directory

Step 4. Run `composer update` command

Step 5. Run setup upgrade and deploy commands

Step 6. Now install other require modules

Match your composer.json file.

```
{
    "name": "magento/project-community-edition",
    "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "version": "2.4.2",
    "require": {
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.4.2",
        "magento/composer-root-update-plugin": "~1.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "exclude-from-classmap": [
            "**/dev/**",
            "**/update/**",
            "**/Test/**"
        ],
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ],
        "psr-0": {
            "": [
                "app/code/",
                "generated/code/"
            ]
        },
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
            "Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"
        }
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "allure-framework/allure-phpunit": "~1.2.0",
        "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": "^0.7.0",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.16.0",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
        "magento/magento-coding-standard": "*",
        "magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "^3.0",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "~2.7.1",
        "phpcompatibility/php-compatibility": "^9.3",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "^2.8.0",
        "phpstan/phpstan": ">=0.12.3 <=0.12.23",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "~5.0.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "~3.5.4"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "gene/bluefoot": "*"
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\PhpStan\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/PhpStan/",
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        }
    ],
    "extra": {
        "magento-force": "override"
    }
}
```

Comment: It is working, Thnx MP Raj

Comment: Okay good, https://www.integerbyteblog.in/magento/steps-for-the-upgrade-magento2-version/