# How to upgrade Magento from 2.4.1 to 2.4.6

Tags: upgrade, magento-upgrade, magento2.4.1, magento2.4.6

I'm actually on Magento CE version 2.4.1

I need to update it to 2.4.6 (latest version)

I'm in live (I don't have a staging enviroment)

Is there someone who can guide me step to step in upgrading?

Really really thanks

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/367941/update-2-3-4-2-4-x-composer-update-composer-root-update-plugin-it-could-not/367943#367943

Comment: When upgrading Magento from version 2.4.1 to 2.4.6, you may encounter several issues due to the significant differences between the two versions. **I highly recommend setting up a test environment** on your machine (local environment) to perform the upgrade and ensure that everything is working as expected. Once you have completed that work, you can apply the changes to the production environment. I've written a detailed guide for how to upgrade to Magento 2.4.6, you can take a look: https://magetu.com/how-to-upgrade-to-magento-version-2-4-6-or-2-4-5-or-2-4-4/

Answer (score 2):

Please Try below steps for update existing project
First you need to check magento system requirements as per the version which link is given below and update first if required **Like :-** (php, composer, mysql, elastic search) version etc then start work on it.

You can upgrade magento version using command line follow below steps

1. First Enable maintenance mode using a command.
   **php bin/magento maintenance:enable**
2. Take backup of you composer.json file using command.
   **cp composer.json composer.json.bk**
3. Update composer.json file
   **composer require-commerce magento/product-community-edition 2.4.6 --no-update**
4. Composer update
   **composer update**
5. Please run below commands one by one.
   **php bin/magento cache:clean**
   **rm -rf var/cache/***

   **rm -rf var/page_cache/***

   **rm -rf generated/code/***

   **php bin/magento setup:upgrade**

   **php bin/magento setup:di:compile**

   **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f**
6. Disable Maintainance Mode.
   **php bin/magento maintenance:disable**