# How to upgrade Magento from 2.4.6 to 2.4.7-beta

Tags: upgrade, magento2.4.6

I am currently attempting to upgrade to the latest beta of 2.4.7.

However it only seems to recognize:

```
composer require-commerce magento/product-community-edition 2.4.7-beta2 --no-update
```

But when I then run

```
composer update --with-all-dependencies
```

I then get:

```
Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires magento/product-community-edition 2.4.7-beta2 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.4.7-beta2].
- magento/product-community-edition 2.4.7-beta2 requires magento/magento2-base 2.4.7-beta2 -> found magento/magento2-base[2.4.7-beta2] but it does not match your minimum-stability.
```

What is the correct approach?
[I followed this successfully to get from 2.4.5 to 2.4.6 without a problem:](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/368385/how-to-upgrade-magento-from-2-4-1-to-2-4-6)

I notice it states my version 2.4.5 but when I login to Magento it says 2.4.6?

My composer.json file is as follows:

```
{
    "name": "magento/project-community-edition",
    "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": true,
            "laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin": true,
            "magento/*": true
        },
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "version": "2.4.5",
    "require": {
        "magento/composer-dependency-version-audit-plugin": "~0.1",
        "magento/composer-root-update-plugin": "~2.0",
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.4.7-beta2",
        
    },
    "autoload": {
        "exclude-from-classmap": [
            "**/dev/**",
            "**/update/**",
            "**/Test/**"
        ],
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ],
        "psr-0": {
            "": [
                "app/code/",
                "generated/code/"
            ]
        },
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/"
        }
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "allure-framework/allure-phpunit": "^2",
        "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": "^1.0",
        "dg/bypass-finals": "^1.4",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "^3.22",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "^0.8",
        "magento/magento-coding-standard": "*",
        "magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "^4.4.2",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "^2.10",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "^2.12.0",
        "phpstan/phpstan": "^1.9",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "^6.0",
        "symfony/finder": "^5.4"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "gene/bluefoot": "*"
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\PhpStan\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/PhpStan/",
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "extra": {
        "magento-force": "override"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the **stability** on your composer.json file to allow it to use less stable packages in order to get 2.4.7-beta.

```
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"prefer-stable": true,
```

Change this ^ to this:

```
"minimum-stability": "beta",
"prefer-stable": true,
```

Simple when you know how. Here is a list of the values accepted in **[minimum-stability](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/what-is-minimum-stability-in-composer/)** which may differ depending on the package you are trying to use.