Issues Upgrading from 2.4.6-p7 to 2.4.7
I have updated all 2.4.6 versions with no issues using the same commands, however trying to update to 2.4.7 and keep getting errors. I have tried two diffrent commands per instructions and get two diffrent errors. Listed below are each command being used with their errors
composer require-commerce magento/community-edition 2.4.7 --no-update
Running native execute...
./composer.json has been updated

composer require-commerce magento/product-community-edition 2.4.7 --no-update
Deprecation Notice: VersionSelector::findBestCandidate with ignored platform reqs as bool|array is deprecated since Composer 2.2, use an instance of PlatformRequirementFilterInterface instead. in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer2/src/Composer/Package/Version/VersionSelector.php:81
Deprecation Notice: VersionSelector::findBestCandidate with ignored platform reqs as bool|array is deprecated since Composer 2.2, use an instance of PlatformRequirementFilterInterface instead. in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer2/src/Composer/Package/Version/VersionSelector.php:81


I have tried the steps Mufaddal Dhansurawala mentioned and once I got to "composer update" this is the results.
Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires magento/community-edition 2.4.7-p2 -> satisfiable by magento/community-edition[2.4.7-p2].
- magento/product-community-edition 2.4.7-p2 requires magento/magento2-base 2.4.7-p2 -> satisfiable by magento/magento2-base[2.4.7-p2].
- Only one of these can be installed: magento/magento2-base[2.4.7-p2], magento/community-edition[2.4.7-p2]. They both replace trentrichardson/jquery-timepicker-addon and thus cannot coexist.
- Root composer.json requires magento/product-community-edition 2.4.7-p2 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.4.7-p2].
Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

composer version?

Please try https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/368385/how-to-upgrade-magento-from-2-4-1-to-2-4-6/368387#368387

Composer 2.2.17
For some reason it will not let me update to a newer/latest version. I have tried the sudo commands and keeps asking for a password I do not have

simple steps that i have followed to upgrade to 2.4.7-p1 are:


-> composer require-commerce magento/community-edition 2.4.7-p1 --no-update

it added a line in my composer.json


"magento/community-edition": "2.4.7-p1",

after this i have just updated the meta package version to update:

change this line "magento/magento-cloud-metapackage": ">=2.4.6 <2.4.7", to  "magento/magento-cloud-metapackage": ">=2.4.7 <2.4.8",

and then

composer update -w

Dont worry about these Deprecation Notice just follow the steps.


for safety purpose your composer version should be 2.2.21 for stable,
you can update the version as well by using this command sudo composer
self-update 2.2.21 and then perform upgrade after upgrading update
your composer version to 2.7


I see the line "magento/product-community-edition": "2.4.7"
But do not see the other line in composer.json "magento/magento-cloud-metapackage": ">=2.4.6 <2.4.7",  that you mentioned

use composer update -w

@nihalmalik Any idea about this error https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/375766/57334

Since the time I originally posted my issue trying to update from 2.4.6 to 2.4.7-p2, I was able to get it done recently, however I am now attempting to update from 2.4.7-p2 to 2.4.7-p3 and having the same issue with the following message. Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to fix the issue preventing me from updating.
Here is the message I get trying to update after running the following command then goes back to the command promt:
composer require-commerce magento/product-community-edition 2.4.7-p3 --no-update
Deprecation Notice: VersionSelector::findBestCandidate with ignored platform reqs as bool|array is deprecated since Composer 2.2, use an instance of PlatformRequirementFilterInterface instead. in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer2/src/Composer/Package/Version/VersionSelector.php:81
Deprecation Notice: VersionSelector::findBestCandidate with ignored platform reqs as bool|array is deprecated since Composer 2.2, use an instance of PlatformRequirementFilterInterface instead. in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer2/src/Composer/Package/Version/VersionSelector.php:81
Running native execute...
./composer.json has been updated

Any idea about this error.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/375766/57334
