How to upgrade composer manually using latest composer.phar file in Windows platform
I want to upgrade/downgrade composer version manually, i have downloaded latest version composer.phar file from https://getcomposer.org/download/2.8.4/composer.phar
I am using windows platform. At which location i need to update files.
Error:


You can download any version of Composer from the official website at https://getcomposer.org/download/. You can use each version directly from the directory where you saved it. Since each composer.phar file is a standalone package, you can have multiple versions in the same directory without any issues. Just remember to rename each file to distinguish between different versions, such as composer_284.phar for version 2.8.4 and composer_283.phar for for version 2.8.3.

I am using windows, where i need to place the downloaded compose.phar file?

You mean  C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Composer?
Correct me if i am wrong.

You can place that file (and other versions) in any suitable place.

I am placed composer.phar (version 1.10.27) at the location, C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2. If i run the command C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2>composer -v return 2.0.8 instead of 1.10.27.
If i make any silly mistake, apologies me, i am new to this, advice pls.

Phar files just work as portable executable files which can be run using PHP. There is nothing fancy to be done, you just need follow following steps ;

Make sure the version of composer.phar is compatible with your PHP version.
Place composer.phar in your Magento instance's root.
Run composer commands using


php composer.phar [arguments] [options]

instead of

composer [arguments] [options]

Nothing else should really change.

I try to run following cmd,
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition=2.4.3-p3 -vvv
But i am getting an error
https://i.sstatic.net/Cbocq7Pr.png

Any idea about this error

There maybe issue with your network, it's not able to reach repo.magento.com. Try pinging this domain to see if it's reachable i.e "ping repo.magento.com"

When i enter repo.magento.com in browser its redirect to commercemarketplace.adobe.com, any advice on this?

ping repo.magento.com -> Timeout error, but in browser redirect to commercemarketplace.adobe.com

This seems to be network issue as I can access repo.magento.com just fine.
